# Xcode dropping a song in simulator in iTunes saving to iTunes test library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Hello does anybody know how to drop a song into iTunes library on the simulator and get it to save into the iTunes test library for Xcode simulator so  I can test on my app. When I drop a song in it will play the song no problem but it does not save so i can try it out. Anybody know how to do this? Search and saw no good answer.

Thanks,

- Colin